# Z fighting and mesh incorrect rendering in Eevee

Tags: mesh, eevee-render-engine

I have a scene with these objects look alright in perspective view, but messed up in camera and rendering output! It's in Eevee.

Everything fighting and not rendering correctly! Seems like everything is mixed together! XD

non is Grease pencil, all is standard materials!

Any option or optimization may I forgot? Any fixes?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide some screenshots so we can see the problem?

Comment: sorry, refresh the page and see the GIF!

Comment: Thanks, the problem is clearly obvious now :) I'm sorry I don't have any immediate thoughts on what might be causing this.

Comment: Have you duplicated any of the objects and left both visible?

Comment: Hey ppl, watch the answer, @Markus von Broady posted here! ❤

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem appears when you switch from *Material Preview* to *Rendered* view: [image] then it's most likely either a problem with your lightning setup (which by default is not used in the former and is replaced by 'default' lightning), or an Eevee vs Cycles problem. In your case it doesn't look like either of those.

---

If your problem appears when switching from 3D viewport to a rendered image, then it's likely a problem either with compositing or different settings for viewport and render, like subdivision levels or some objects hidden in viewport but not in render - especially the latter is known to cause z-fighting issues.

---

Finally if the problem appears when switching between a normal 3D Viewport view, and a camera view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>), the problem is likely related to camera clipping settings. The larger is the camera clipping range, the further the middle of this range is from zero, and therefore its significant digits have larger magnitude. Basically, decrease the clipping range / make sure it's roughly the same as the viewport's clipping range:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem was last issue you mentioned here... Camera Clip Start, camera clip start was 0.001! I changed it to 1 and prob solved! 
I wanted my camera to show very close objects, but solved the prob by apart it from close objects.